# Python PIL ImageTkでRuntimeErrorが発生する。

Tags: python3, tkinter, pil

Tkを使用して、Imageファイルを描画しているのですが、部分テストのために、一部のダイアログのみ描画配置などを確認するため、ソースコードを一部流用していました。
今まで動作していた以下の関数からエラーが発生しました。

```py
    def LoadImage(self):
        self.img_single = self._chk_image_file_(".\\icon\\mon_s.gif")

        self.img_single = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img_single)

        return
```

エラーの内容

```py
RuntimeError: Too early to create image
Exception ignored in: <bound method PhotoImage.__del__ of <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x0000029C4F87A9E8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 123, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

全ソースコード

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk,ImageDraw


class class_Pattern_main(object):    
    def __init__(self):

        self.screen_w = 300
        self.screen_h = 200
        self.dlg_pos_x = 10
        self.dlg_pos_y = 10
        self.dlg_pad = 4

        self.sticky = tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W

        self.LoadImage()


    def createMainWindow(self):

        obj = ttk.tkinter.Tk() 

        geo_string = str(self.screen_w) + "x" + str(self.screen_h) + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_x)  + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_y) 

        obj.geometry(geo_string) 

        return obj

    def _chk_image_file_(self,f_path):
        try:
            # ファイルを読み込んで64x64にリサイズ
            ret_obj = Image.open(f_path).resize((64,64))
        except IOError:
            #Logに残すとか
            msg_text = "{0}{1}{2}".format(self.log_header,"指定されたアイコンファイルが読み込めません。" ,f_path)

            # 代わりとなるイメージを作成して返す。
            ret_obj = Image.new('RGB',(64,64),(150,150,150))
            draw = ImageDraw.ImageDraw(ret_obj)
            draw.rectangle((4,4,60,60), fill = None, outline = (250,30,30),width=2)
            draw.line((60,4,4,60), fill = (250,30,30),width=2)

        return ret_obj           

    def LoadImage(self):
        self.img_single = self._chk_image_file_(".\\icon\\mon_s.gif")

        self.img_single = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img_single)

        return

    def _PatternDialog(self, parent):

        self.dlg_width = 1260
        self.dlg_height = 680
        self.dlg_h_btn = 30
        self.dlg_pad = 8

        self.dev_dialog = tk.Toplevel(parent,background = 'aliceblue')

        title_str = " イメージ表示 : " 

        self.dev_dialog.title(title_str)

        # MainWindowの表示位置を反映して表示位置を決めたい。

        self.dev_dialog.geometry(str(self.dlg_width) + "x"+ str(self.dlg_height) )

        _InFrame_ = ttk.Frame(
            self.dev_dialog
            )

        _Label_ = tk.Label(
            _InFrame_,
            image = self.img_single
        )


        _Label_.pack()
        _InFrame_.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_obj = class_Pattern_main()

    MainWindow_obj = screen_obj.createMainWindow()

    MainWindow_obj.after(100,screen_obj._PatternDialog(MainWindow_obj))
    MainWindow_obj.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結論として、呼び出しが早すぎました。**init**()において呼び出してしまっているのが原因です。
子ダイアログを表示させる_PatternDialog関数の先頭にself.LoadImage()を移動させました。
参考リンクは以下の通りです。

[RuntimeError: Too early to create image - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861528/runtimeerror-too-early-to-create-image)

修正したソースコード

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk,ImageDraw


class class_Pattern_main(object):    
    def __init__(self):

        self.screen_w = 300
        self.screen_h = 200
        self.dlg_pos_x = 10
        self.dlg_pos_y = 10
        self.dlg_pad = 4

        self.sticky = tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W

        # ここではだめなのね
        #self.LoadImage()


    def createMainWindow(self):

        obj = ttk.tkinter.Tk() 

        geo_string = str(self.screen_w) + "x" + str(self.screen_h) + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_x)  + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_y) 

        obj.geometry(geo_string) 

        return obj

    def _chk_image_file_(self,f_path):
        try:
            # ファイルを読み込んで64x64にリサイズ
            ret_obj = Image.open(f_path).resize((64,64))
        except IOError:
            #Logに残すとか
            msg_text = "{0}{1}{2}".format(self.log_header,"指定されたアイコンファイルが読み込めません。" ,f_path)

            # 代わりとなるイメージを作成して返す。
            ret_obj = Image.new('RGB',(64,64),(150,150,150))
            draw = ImageDraw.ImageDraw(ret_obj)
            draw.rectangle((4,4,60,60), fill = None, outline = (250,30,30),width=2)
            draw.line((60,4,4,60), fill = (250,30,30),width=2)

        return ret_obj           

    def LoadImage(self):
        self.img_single = self._chk_image_file_(".\\icon\\mon_s.gif")

        self.img_single = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img_single)

        return

    def _PatternDialog(self, parent):
        self.LoadImage()

        self.dlg_width = 1260
        self.dlg_height = 680
        self.dlg_h_btn = 30
        self.dlg_pad = 8

        self.dev_dialog = tk.Toplevel(parent,background = 'aliceblue')

        title_str = " イメージ表示 : " 

        self.dev_dialog.title(title_str)

        # MainWindowの表示位置を反映して表示位置を決めたい。

        self.dev_dialog.geometry(str(self.dlg_width) + "x"+ str(self.dlg_height) )

        _InFrame_ = ttk.Frame(
            self.dev_dialog
            )

        _Label_ = tk.Label(
            _InFrame_,
            image = self.img_single
        )


        _Label_.pack()
        _InFrame_.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_obj = class_Pattern_main()

    MainWindow_obj = screen_obj.createMainWindow()

    MainWindow_obj.after(100,screen_obj._PatternDialog(MainWindow_obj))
    MainWindow_obj.mainloop()
```